# If I used Wish to become immune to being seen via Truesight and stand in an area of magical darkness, can a creature with Truesight see me?

Tags: dnd-5e, vision-and-light, wish, special-senses

As the title says, does standing inside an area of magical darkness, while being immune from detection through truesight (not the spell, but the monster ability), render me unseen from a creature that has truesight?

On the one hand, the answer might be yes. I am undetectable by truesight now, and truesight is what is enabling the creature to see me.

On the other hand, the answer might be no. Truesight allows the creature to see through the magical darkness and I am not actually invisible.

Which is the answer that has more adherence to the rules as written? Or is this a gray area in the rules?

Answer (score 8):

## It's going to depend on the DM

*[Wish](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wish)* is clear in what it's allowable as a standard wish and the closest is below:

> You grant up to ten creatures you can see immunity to a single spell or other magical effect for 8 hours. For instance, you could make yourself and all your companions immune to a lich's life drain attack.

However, since you are saying this is a monster trait and not the spell, then it's not a magical effect, so this doesn't apply. Which means we're back in DM ruling territory in terms of the effects and how to adjudicate them.